# Applying functions to conditional rows with output in new column in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, if-statement

I have a df of around 700 observations, in which I have created three different `functions` to calculate distances using three different methods. I want to run one of the three functions per row based on conditional statements. I'm somewhat of an R noobie, so what I've come to so far is to use an `if` statement inside a `for` loop.

What I want to do:

```
sightings <- data.frame(a=c(NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1), b=c(NA, NA, "HO", "HO", "LA", "LA"), 
                        c=c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600), d = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
#our df 

> sightings
   a    b   c  d
1 NA <NA> 100 NA
2  1 <NA> 200 NA
3 NA   HO 300 NA
4  1   HO 400 NA
5 NA   LA 500 NA
6  1   LA 600 NA

#desired output
   a    b   c   d
1 NA <NA> 100 100
2  1 <NA> 200 200
3 NA   HO 300 300
4  1   HO 400 467
5 NA   LA 500 500
6  1   LA 600 666
```

I have two `functions`: one for generating distance in `df$d` using `df$b == "HO"` and another for `df$b == "LA"` (both include multiple trigonometric functions including values from columns not mentioned here).

So in the cases where `df$b == "HO" & df$a != NA` I want to run the `ho.function`, with the output in `df$d`, and `df$b == "LA" & df$a != NA` run the `la.function` and output in `df$d`

I have devised an `if` statement which I've tried putting in a `for` loop, but to no luck (new to both `for` loops and `if` statements)

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df$b[i] == "LA" && is.na(df$a) == FALSE){
    df$d <- la.function 
  } else if (df$b[i] == "HO" && is.na(df$a) == FALSE){
    df$d <- ho.function
  } else {
    df$d <- df$c
  }
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting `df$d == df$c` `> TRUE`, so it feels like R is just jumping over my first two `if` statements?

Anyone with any knowledge/experience with this? Am I using the functions correctly?

Comment: What is the input to `la.function` and `ho.function` ?

Comment: Maybe change `is.na(df$a)` to `is.na(df$a[i])` and `df$d` to `df$d[i]`

Comment: Inputs are radians from another column (for `ho.function`), and radians and distance for `la.function`. I added the `[i]`in the different arguments, but still nothing

Comment: You need to make this example reproducible, you have shared the data but it is not clear how do you apply `la.function` and what is the output it returns. You are just assigning `la.function` to `df$d`. It's like just assigning function `mean` which does not make any sense unless you pass some value to it like `mean(1:10)`

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the details of `la.function` and `ho.function` and if they are vectorized. So keeping the code simple we can use `for` loop like :

```
for(i in 1:nrow(sightings)) {
  if(sightings$b[i] == "LA" && !is.na(sightings$a[i])) {
    sightings$d[i] <- la.function(sightings$c[i]) 
  } else if (sightings$b[i] == "HO" && !is.na(sightings$a[i])){
    sightings$d[i] <- ho.function(sightings$c[i])
  } else {
    df$d[i] <- df$c[i]
  }
}
```

It is important to subset the data with `[i]` to update the particular row and not the entire column.